# Angularjs: select item in select control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In Angularjs I have a select control:

```
<select ng-model="modtipoProdotto.Ruoli" ng-options="ruolo.Name for ruolo in ruoli" class="form-control" multiple size="8"></select>
```

That I populate with url request in the controller:

```
gestionale.controller('productController', function($scope, $http, Restangular){
   ...
   ...
   $scope.ruoli = "data from url";
}
```

The object `$scope.ruoli` has 8 elements.
Now I want select an item in the select control and for example, in the angularjs controller, i've tried:

```
$scope.modtipoProdotto.Ruoli = $scope.ruoli[0];
```

Why this doesn't works?

Comment: after your data loads, what do you get when you do console.log($scope.ruoli); ?

Comment: You need to add that code *after* you get the data from your url, not before - is that so in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the default option in the `<select>` do this:

```
$scope.modtipoProdotto.Ruoli = "someValue";
```

To get the selected value from the `<select>` do this:

```
var someValue = $scope.modtipoProdotto.Ruoli
```

Also the `ng-options` variable has to be an object array, not a string.
try changing `$scope.ruoli = "data from url";` to this:

```
$scope.ruolo = [
    {
        text : 'SomeText',
        value: 'SomeValue'
    },
    {
        text : 'SomeOtherText',
        value: 'SomeOtherValue'
    },
]
```

And change your html to this:

```
<select ng-model="ruoli.value" ng-selected="0" ng-options="ruoli.value as ruoli.text for ruoli in ruolo"></select>
```